# How to sort array by first item in string in descending order on C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bubble-sort

I don't know what to do, my program is not working

I need to sort a two-dimensional array by the first elements of a row in descending order by rearranging the rows
(need to sort string without sort item)

Let's say I'm given an array:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

As a result of the program, I need to get:
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
`

```
using System;

namespace BubbleSort
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Объявление массива и его размерности
            const int n = 3;
            int bubble;
            int[,] A = 
            { 
                { 1, 2, 3 },
                { 4, 5, 6 },
                { 7, 8, 9 },
            };
            //Алгоритм пузырьковой сортировки
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (A[i, 0] < A[i++, 0])
                    {
                        for(j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
                        {
                            bubble = A[i, j];
                            A[i, j] = A[i, j+1];
                            A[i, j+1] = bubble;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Вывод массива
            for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(A[y, x] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Is this a school assignment to use bubble sort, or is anything OK?

Comment: this my study work, i don't know how i can sort raw in array

Comment: FYI, the Bubble Sort algorithm is documented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation - What you have here at the moment is not that.

Comment: I know how work bubble sort, i dont know how to create function for swap raw in array
I do algorithm for one-dimensional array, but i dont understand how swap raw in array

Comment: If (0, 0) < (1, 0) then (0, 0) needs to be swapped with (1, 0), (0, 1) with (1, 1), and (0, 2) with (1, 2). A simple `for` loop across the "row" would achieve this. If you were using a jagged array (an array of arrays) instead of a 2d array, it would be easier as you could just swap the nested arrays, rather than individual items.

Comment: i try this with for loop, but i have error out of range

Comment: Then debug your code and find out why. Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: ok, thanks you very much, i go to try debug

Comment: Tag me (`@programmingllama`) after you've tried for a bit and I'll fix your code if you can't find the source of the problem. It's better to find it by yourself though (for your own experience).

Comment: @programmingllama

`for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                if (A[i, 0] < A[i + 1, 0])
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
                        {
                            bubble = A[k, j];
                            A[k, j] = A[k + 1, j];
                            A[k + 1, j] = bubble;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
and i get array 
4 5 6\
7 8 9\
1 2 3\

Comment: That's because you don't yet have a full bubble sort. You need to repeat the process until no swaps occur. Refer to the [pseudocode implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation). Each pass will only swap an item with its neighbour.

Comment: I would have something like `bool swapped; do { swapped = false; /*your existing code*/ } while (swapped);`, and then modify your existing code so that inside `if (A[i, 0] < A[i + 1, 0])` you set `swapped = true;`.

Comment: i add one more loop for before `for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)`, but is don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in your comments, I'm not sure why you have a nested loop for swapping the values since a single loop will do. I've removed that here.

If you refer to the [pseudocode implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation) on Wikipedia, you'll see that you need to keep running multiple passes across the array until everything is sorted. You can do this like so:

```cs
bool swapped;
do
{
    swapped = false; // reset swapped
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) // loop through all but the last row
    {
        if (A[i, 0] < A[i + 1, 0]) // determine if this row needs to be swapped with the next row
        {
            swapped = true; // mark swapped
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) // swap each item in row i with each item in row i+1
            {
                int tmp = A[i, j];
                A[i, j] = A[i + 1, j];
                A[i + 1, j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
while (swapped); // if we swapped anything, we need to make another pass to ensure the array is sorted
```

We can also do away with the need for `n` by using `.GetUpperBound(dimension)` which returns a value between `0` and `n - 1` (where n is the *count* of items in the array in that dimension). Because the result is effectively `n - 1`, I've modified the loop conditions slightly:

```cs
bool swapped;
do
{
    swapped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        if (A[i, 0] < A[i + 1, 0])
        {
            swapped = true;
            for (int j = 0; j <= A.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                int tmp = A[i, j];
                A[i, j] = A[i + 1, j];
                A[i + 1, j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
while (swapped);
```

We can also refer to the "Optimizing bubble sort" section of the Wikipedia page and implement that instead, which will make our code run more optimally:

```cs
int n = A.GetUpperBound(0); // get the initial value of n
do
{
    int newn = 0; // default newn to 0, so if no items are visited, it will remain 0 and the loop will exit
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i, 0] < A[i + 1, 0])
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= A.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                int tmp = A[i, j];
                A[i, j] = A[i + 1, j];
                A[i + 1, j] = tmp;
            }
            newn = i; // store the current (highest) value of i swapped
        }
    }
    n = newn; // set the value of n to the highest value of i swapped
}
while (n > 0); // loop until n == 0
```

The logic here (as explained on Wikipedia) is that by the end of the first pass, the last item is in the correct position. By the end of the second pass, the second-to-last and last items are in the correct position, and so on. So each time, we can visit one less item. When we have 0 items to visit, we have 0 items to swap, and the sort is complete.

You can see this optimised version in [this YouTube visualisation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cq7SMsQBEUw).

Comment: Oh how stupid I am, thank you very much for your time and such an extensive explanation of my problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the line

```
if (A[i, 0] < A[i++, 0])
```

should read

```
if  (A[i, 0] < A[i+ 1, 0])
```

Comment: this dont work, i have a error out of array